# don't know how this virtual directory structure was setup on iis6

Tags: iis-6

Our development server has a setup as follows:

```
\\DEVSRVR\WEBSITES\COMMON
└───include
```

Here is where all css and script files resides. They are required by various web applications

```
\\DEVSRVR\WEBSITES\TESTING\SAM
├───Backup
│   └───bin
├───bin
└───help
```

Here is where an application resides. Suppose there is an aspx page under the folder called SAM, we'd normally issue an http request as follows:

```
http://testing.apps/sam/default.aspx
```

We believe that *testing.apps* virtual name points to `\\\\devsrvr\websites\testing` folder.

Suppose there is a css file called menu.css inside common/include. We'd simply have to make the following http call to get it:

```
http://testing.apps/common/include/menu3.css
```

This works!!! I don't understand how? There is no such folder called **common** inside of **testing**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS does not require the web site's directory structure to match the on-disk directory structure.

It's possible you have a website configured bound to the `testing.apps` hostname which maps to `\\devsrvr\websites\testing`, then inside the `/sam` path you have a [virtual directory](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true) pointing to `\\devsrvr\websites\common`.

(note that the IIS server probably uses local paths like "`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\common`" rather than UNC paths)